# Diagonal Difference challenge in C# failing Test on HackerRank

Tags: c#, .net

I'm relatively new to online code challenges and somewhat confused about how HackerRank works.

The following implementation should work fine for the Diagonal Difference challenge:

```
// Test case 0
List<List<int>> arr = new List<List<int>>();
arr.Add(new List<int> { 3 });
arr.Add(new List<int> { 11, 2, 4 });
arr.Add(new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 });
arr.Add(new List<int> { 10, 8, -12 });
// Sum across the primary diagonal: 11 + 5 - 12 = 4
// Sum across the secondary diagonal: 4 + 5 + 10 = 19
// Absolute Difference: |4 - 19| = 15

// Test case 1
/*
List<List<int>> arr = new List<List<int>>();
arr.Add(new List<int> { 4 });
arr.Add(new List<int> { -1, 1, -7, -8 });
arr.Add(new List<int> { -10, -8, -5, -2 });
arr.Add(new List<int> { 0, 9, 7, -1 });
arr.Add(new List<int> { 4, 4, -2, 1 });
*/

// By definition, the data structure already provides the size.
arr.RemoveAt(0);
List<List<int>> matrix = arr;

List<int> principalDiagonal = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Count; i++)
{
    principalDiagonal.Add(matrix[i][i]);
}

List<int> secondaryDiagonal = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Count; i++)
{
    secondaryDiagonal.Add(matrix[i][matrix.Count - 1 - i]);
}

int absoluteDifference = Math.Abs(principalDiagonal.Sum() - secondaryDiagonal.Sum());
```

I've even tried it on a .NET Fiddle with a couple of their own test cases and it works as expected: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6s4aU2

However, when I submit the code it is being taken as a wrong answer, curiously without any errors, just different results based on their test cases.

```
// HackerRank's "Console" message 

/*
    Compiler Message
    Wrong Answer
    Input (stdin)
    3
    11 2 4
    4 5 6
    10 8 -12
    Your Output (stdout)
    3
*/
```

Is anyone having a similar experience with this platform?

Comment: What is the correct answer for the failed test case you've shown? The problem you're trying to solve should be described in the question. I have no idea what Diagonal Difference is and I'm not going to search for it on another site.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I've updated the code with the correct answer for Test case 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you changed how the data are read. (so now you are reading from the static table that you created)

The following code is working (is your solution inside the provided method)

```html
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using System;

class Result
{

    /*
     * Complete the 'diagonalDifference' function below.
     *
     * The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
     * The function accepts 2D_INTEGER_ARRAY arr as parameter.
     */

    public static int diagonalDifference(List<List<int>> matrix)
    {
        List<int> principalDiagonal = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Count; i++)
        {
            principalDiagonal.Add(matrix[i][i]);
        }

        List<int> secondaryDiagonal = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Count; i++)
        {
            secondaryDiagonal.Add(matrix[i][matrix.Count - 1 - i]);
        }

        int absoluteDifference = Math.Abs(principalDiagonal.Sum() - secondaryDiagonal.Sum());
        return absoluteDifference;
    }

}

class Solution
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH"), true);

        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());

        List<List<int>> arr = new List<List<int>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            arr.Add(Console.ReadLine().TrimEnd().Split(' ').ToList().Select(arrTemp => Convert.ToInt32(arrTemp)).ToList());
        }

        int result = Result.diagonalDifference(arr);

        textWriter.WriteLine(result);

        textWriter.Flush();
        textWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Doing too many of these in a day and switching between languages is affecting my focus.